# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Issues Failed to deploy on all servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Yesterday and today i tried to deploy on aws eb but I always get this error:

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Info. Command is executing on all instances.
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Info to Severe. None of the instances are sending data.
ERROR: Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-0632a672238b6ee0b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED).../opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 166, in npm_install
    raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.2.3-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status -9.
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0632a672238b6ee0b'. Aborting the operation.
ERROR: Failed to deploy application.

ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
```

The built was successfull yesterday and i tried to push the old version and on another instance i just tried to deploy again. every instance is now in status severe or degraded.

Is this a aws issues, did i do something wrong? I did all the steps i do everyday and until now i never had any issues. Even after i uploaded the old applicationzip which was okay nothing changed.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I am having exactly the same issue. Build started to fail during the last weekend. Due to logs, the problem seems to be that while running *npm install*, the process runs out of memory. It doesn't matter whether I deploy directly or use a Docker container.

I am using a free tier micro instance with 1 GB of memory. I just can't understand why it worked before and now it doesn't work even if I deploy the same version that was working before...

Comment: yes exactly the same here. ive opened an issue on aws

Comment: @gope any solution here?

Comment: I know this is old, but I'm having the same problem. Idk why it suddenly doesn't work

Comment: I know its freakin old but i write my workaround: I created a new EB instance and swapped urls with the existing one. That way it worked. Never figured out why that happend